# How to Implement Binary Search Trees (Within the parameters of my questions)?

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, nodes

I am struggling in a data structures course where my professor is either absent or not answering. I have an assignment due within a day or so and have no clue where to even start in terms of answering them. If somebody could explain what to do and how it'd be much appreciated. Also, I'm somewhat new to StackOverflow, if I misformatted my question or did something wrong please let me know before a downvote, I would just like some help, thanks.

> 1. Write the definition of the method nodeCount that returns the number of nodes in a binary tree. Add this method to the class BinaryTree and create a program (the main class with the main method) to test this method. (Note: To test your algorithm, first create a binary search tree).
> 2. Write a method, swapSubtrees, that swaps all of the left and right subtrees of a binary tree.  Add this method to the class BinaryTree and create a program (the main class with the main method) to test this method. (Note: To test your algorithm, first create a binary search tree).

Comment: Homework questions like this are usually too broad for Stack Overflow unless you can narrow it down to something specific about your own attempt. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Is there anywhere or anybody you can direct me to that can possibly help with answering these questions? I'm very stuck and need help.

Comment: I would suggest doing a Google search for something like *'binary tree count nodes java'*.

Answer (score -1):

You can find a tutorial on how to implement a binary tree in java [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-binary-tree).

To count the nodes in a tree you should try to use a recursive method that count's and summs up the size of the sub-trees. In pseudocode:

```
int count(TreeNode node):
    if (node.hasNoMoreSubNodes):
        return 1
    else:
        sum = count(node.left) + count(node.right) + 1
        return sum
```

I'm not quite shure what's the point in the second question. You could do something like this (pseudocode):

```
void swapSubTrees(TreeNode node):
    TreeNode tmp = node.left
    node.left = node.right
    node.right = tmp
```

This would swap the subtrees of the binary-tree, but after this the structure you have is no longer a `binary-search-tree`, but only a `binary-tree`. So this operation would be quite useless if it's executed on a binary-search-tree...

Hope this helps.

Comment: to be precise, it still would be a binary tree, but not a binary search tree.

Comment: And your `count` method doesn't take `null`s into account.

Comment: It wouldn't matter if the pseudo code was correct, but it's not.